# SQL Developer does not open in macOs?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am facing an issue with SQL Developer whenever I start SQL Developer it simply keeps on loading and does not open [image] I tried running the sqldeveloper executable in the path SQLDeveloper.app/Contents/Resources/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin and I got this exception

```
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
at java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:694)
at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:123)
at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:311)
at org.netbeans.Stamps.asByteBuffer(Stamps.java:218)
at org.netbeans.Stamps.asByteBuffer(Stamps.java:186)
at org.netbeans.Archive.<init>(Archive.java:120)
at org.netbeans.JarClassLoader.initializeCache(JarClassLoader.java:108)
at org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader.run(MainImpl.java:343)
at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.initialize(CLIHandler.java:598)
at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.initialize(CLIHandler.java:384)
at org.netbeans.MainImpl.execute(MainImpl.java:193)
at org.netbeans.MainImpl.main(MainImpl.java:85)
at org.netbeans.Main.main(Main.java:83)
at oracle.ide.osgi.boot.OracleIdeLauncher.launchNbMain(OracleIdeLauncher.java:446)
at oracle.ide.osgi.boot.OracleIdeLauncher.main(OracleIdeLauncher.java:322)**
```

What is the issue here and can some one help me debug this.

Comment: CD $HOME/.sqldeveloper In there you'll see a system19.2 directory. Rename it, try again. Also there is version 19.4 you can grab as well. Version 20.2 will be available shortly

Comment: Thanks @thatjeffsmith I tried renaming the folder but did not work I installed the 19.4 version and it works now.

Answer (score 2):

When you are working with a lot of worksheets and reports or try to open large SQL files, you may run into “Java Heap Space” errors.

To fix this problem you need to increase the Xmx (maximum heap size).

Here is how:

- Close all open SQL-Developer instances.
- Find the **sqldeveloper.conf** file

**Windows:**

goto the directory where the SQL-Developer program is installed.

goto the subdirectory `sqldeveloper\bin`

**Mac OS X:**

1. goto your applications folder (`/Applications`)
2. open the SQLDeveloper-App via context menu (right mouse click)
3. goto the subdirectory `Contents/Resources/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin`
4. Open the file `sqldeveloper.conf` with the text editor of your choice.
5. Add a new line with the following text to the file: `AddVMOption -Xmx1024M`
6. Save the file.

Comment: also for mac OS other than the above steps, I had to delete the .sqldeveloper directory in the home directory for sqlDeveloper to work again.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `$HOME/.sqldeveloper` keep backup
[.sqldevelper  keeps all ur queries and connection information] and delete this folder to free up SQL Developer Memory issue.

1. After Cleanup Start SQLDeveloper
2. To Retrieve all your connection Go to :
   `~/.sqldeveloper/system21.4.2.018.1706/o.jdeveloper.db.connection\connections.json`
3. Got to [Oracle Connection Import Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI2s2.png)
4. Import all connection by passing connections.json file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

SetJavaHome to right java_home at
.sqldeveloper/21.4.1/product.info