# SQLDeveloper not opening. Stuck In loading

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to open SQLDeveloper 22.2.1 on my macOS Catalina 10.15.6 and it doesn't load more than 10%. I tried deleting and downloading again without success.

I tried the steps in this post: [SQL Developer does not open in macOs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62113772/sql-developer-does-not-open-in-macos)
without any luck. I would appreciate some help
Thanks!

Comment: So you did the steps shown in the 2nd answer? You went to your $HOME/.sqldeveloper folder, found the system22.2.1 folder, and renamed it, and tried opening it again?

Comment: I did not have such a file in $HOME/.sqldeveloper folder. If I'm looking in the wrong place, do you mind providing steps on how to get there, please?

Comment: you don't have a .sqldeveloper folder in your user's home directory?

Comment: When I do Shift+Comand+H (Home) I do not see a .sqldeveloper folder. Am I looking in the wrong place? If yes, please let me know where to look for it. Thanks!

Comment: you have to tell finder to show you hidden folders, if you jump to a terminal and do ls -a you'll see it

Comment: I changed the system22.2.1 folder and it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: now you can go upvote that answer you saidi you tried without luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I removed below files and it worked

~/.sqldeveloper/system21.4.3.063.0100/ rm -rf system_cache
~/.sqldeveloper/system21.4.3.063.0100/ rm -rf oracle.javatools.cache

@thatjeffsmith answer is also correct and one of the way to resolve the issue .